# Why does the and && operator in awk end up changing values in my input file?

Tags: csv, if-statement, awk, logical-operators

Quick question, I am trying to check for certain patterns in my comma-delimited CSV files/data and I need the and operator &&. I choose to work with AWK.

Commands tried:

1:

```
cat file | awk -F "," 'BEGIN{ OFS=FS=","}
                       {if (($1="DIFF" && $2="DIFF" && $3="NODIFF"))
                          $(NF+1)="TRUE";
                        else $(NF+1)="FALSE";
                          print
                       }'  > outfile
```

2:

```
cat file | awk -F "," 'BEGIN{ OFS=FS=","}
                       {if (($1="DIFF" && $2="DIFF" && $3="NODIFF"))
                          $(NF+1)="TRUE";
                        else if (!($1="DIFF" && $2="DIFF" && $3="NODIFF"))
                           $(NF+1)="FALSE";print
                        }' > outfile
```

Input:

```
DIFF,DIFF,NODIFF
DIFF,NODIFF,DIFF
DIFF,DIFF,DIFF
NODIFF,DIFF,DIFF
```

Desired output:

```
DIFF,DIFF,NODIFF,TRUE
DIFF,NODIFF,DIFF,FALSE
DIFF,DIFF,DIFF,FALSE
NODIFF,DIFF,DIFF,FALSE
```

However, this is the output that I get and I don't know how to stop AWK from doing this??

```
1,1,NODIFF,TRUE
1,1,NODIFF,TRUE
1,1,NODIFF,TRUE
1,1,NODIFF,TRUE
```

I thought this was a simple way to do it but apparently I am missing something.

Thanks for any idea/suggestions,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$1="DIFF"` is an assignment operation.

The comparison operator is `==`; try `$1=="DIFF"`, `$2=="DIFF"` and `$3=="NODIFF"`

As for how you generate a pair of `1's` ...

- `awk` is having problems parsing the assignment which it thinks looks like `$1=("DIFF" && $2="DIFF")`
- an assignment is considered 'true' (aka `1`) so `$1=("DIFF" && $2="DIFF")` becomes `$1=("DIFF" && 1)`
- a literal string, all by itself, is considered 'true' (aka `1`) so `$1=("DIFF" && 1)` becomes `$1=(1 && 1)` which in turn becomes `$1=1`
- repeat for `$2=("DIFF" && $3="NODIFF")`
- obviously `$3="NODIFF"` is a more straightforward, simple assignment
- net result: all output lines start with `1,1,NODIFF`

Comment: Thank you so much! I figured something like this was happening but I couldn't get to the bottom of that alone. I changed some things around and now everything works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `cat` when you have file, GNU `AWK` can read on its own. You are attempting to set field separator both using `-F` and setting value of `FS` in `BEGIN`, strictly speaking this is not error, however this is redundant. You mixed `=` (assign) with `==` (equal check) which caused malfunction.

In this particular case you might get task done using just one regular expression following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
DIFF,DIFF,NODIFF
DIFF,NODIFF,DIFF
DIFF,DIFF,DIFF
NODIFF,DIFF,DIFF
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{$(NF+1)=/^DIFF,DIFF,NODIFF/?"TRUE":"FALSE";print}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
DIFF,DIFF,NODIFF,TRUE
DIFF,NODIFF,DIFF,FALSE
DIFF,DIFF,DIFF,FALSE
NODIFF,DIFF,DIFF,FALSE
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that , is both field separator and output field separator, then I set next field to `TRUE` if line starts with (`^`) `DIFF,DIFF,NODIFF` else `FALSE` using so-called ternary operator condition`?`valueiftrue`:`valueiffalse and then `print` line.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

Comment: Thank you! I was using cat as I wanted to keep intermediate files. The separator methods were indeed double, I was waiting until finalizing the script to choose which option I wanted. Thanks for showing another way using REGEX though!